# Ayuda con un programa

Tags: python

Se me pide hacer un programa en el que se pregunte al usuario por una frase y una letra, y muestre por pantalla el número de veces que aparece la letra en la frase. Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Hola Manuel, bienvenido a [es.so]. Las preguntas que sean tareas académicas han de venir siempre acompañadas de un resumen de lo intentado y/o el código que llevas hasta el momento, así como plantear una duda o problema concreto en base a ello para que sean aceptadas en el sitio. Te recomiendo pasarte por [tour] y [ask]. Supongo que se considera trampa, pero es lo que tiene Python.... `print("Hola Caracola".lower().count("c"))` :). Un saludo.

Comment: Si porque estoy aprendiendo los for. Pero gracias de igual modo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías mostrar lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte mejor. A continuación te muestro un ejemplo que puedes implementar en tu caso.

```
entrada_frase = str(input("Introduce una frase: "))
entrada_letra = str(input("Introduce una letra: "))

contador = 0
for i in entrada_frase:
  if i == entrada_letra:
    contador += 1
  print("La letra '%s' aparece %2i veces en la frase '%s'." % (entrada_letra, contador, entrada_frase))
```

Comment: Gracias me ha servido